# MacBook Pro, Windows wifi does not work after wakeup

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, macbook, boot-camp

I have a MacBook Pro 15 with Windows 7 installed through bootcamp. Wifi works fine but after wakeup my computer is not able to detect any wifi networks. I have to restart the computer to make it work again.

Troubleshooting gives me following message: `The broadcom 802.11ac Network Adaprer is experiencing driver- or hardware- related problems.`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try this: In Device Manager / Network adapters, right-click the WiFi adapter and choose Properties. In the Power Management tab, uncheck `Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power` and set `Allow this device to wake the computer` and click OK.

Comment: Did not work but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Control Panel
2. Network and Sharing Center
3. Change Adapter Settings
4. Right Click the adapter you're using
5. Select Properties
6. Select Configure
7. Power Management tab
8. Uncheck "allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"

Comment: It does not fix the problem. I have already tried it.